# How to hide some markup that was added with .after()?

Tags: jquery

In a nav bar I am working with, there is an arrow added to the "Active" item with jquery:

```
$('.top-bar-wrapper li.active a').after('<div class="nav-active-arrow"></div>');
```

That code cannot change, I need to work with it as-is.

What I need to do is hide the .nav-active-arrow markup when a button is clicked. So, I have something along the lines of the following:

```
var navArrow = $('.nav-active-arrow');

$('#nav-bar-churches').click( function(e) {
  churchesBar.show();
  navArrow.hide();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

There is a bit more to it- for instance, I do a .show on a few events. However, the above code isn't working for me, and I'm guessing it's because `.nav-active-arrow` is created in the `.after()` function.

Is my thinking correct? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `$('.nav-active-arrow')` out side click and need to put it in click event to make sure its `availabilty`.

```
$('#nav-bar-churches').click( function(e) {
  var navArrow = $('.nav-active-arrow');
  churchesBar.show();
  navArrow.hide();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your `var navArrow = $('.nav-active-arrow');` inside the click function like this:

```
$('#nav-bar-churches').click( function(e) {    
  churchesBar.show();
  var navArrow = $('.nav-active-arrow');
  navArrow.hide();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Or, even more succinctly:

```
$('#nav-bar-churches').click( function(e) {    
  churchesBar.show();
  $('.nav-active-arrow').hide();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: The reason is because you are 'grabbing' a reference to '.nav-active-arrow' on the load of the page.  (when it does not yet exist) You need to move it to inside the click event, when you are sure that it exists.